# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on an ASUS UX330UA

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, asus, csm

Hello I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu alongside windows 10. I have followed various online guides, created a partition and a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 20.04 using Rufus. Most online guidelines ask you to disable secure boot and fast mood which makes sense to me. However I am then also asked to enable CSM support. My original OS is installed in EFI mode as far as I can tell and from what I have heard and seen installing Ubuntu in legacy mode can then create a whole range of problems. However, if I don’t have CSM support enabled my laptop (ASUS UX330UA) can’t find the bootable USB stick. Is there a workaround, so that I can install Ubuntu in EFI mode or do I have to reinstall windows using legacy mode? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have now figured out this issue, by changing the USB drive to GPT format.